# Android, setReuseAddress doesn't work

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

I've looked at the other answers concerning this question but they mostly state to call the `setReuseAddress (true)` before binding the socket. But I'm doing that and it still doesn't work, can someone help me out here?

```
SocketChannel tunnel = SocketChannel.open();

if (!protect(tunnel.socket())){
throw new IllegalStateException("Can not protect tunnel");}

Log.i("TAG", "test");
tunnel.socket().setReuseAddress(true);
tunnel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(localAddress, localPort));
Log.i("TAG", "bind test");
tunnel.connect(new InetSocketAddress(destAddress, destPort));
tunnel.configureBlocking(false);

packet.position(0);
packet.limit(length);
Log.i("TAG", "schreibe: " + tunnel.write(packet));
packet.clear();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work for TCP unless the prior socket on the same port is bound on a different IP address excluding 0.0.0.0. Windows excepted as always.